# Building a portal landing page and would like to add a digital clock

Tags: widget, xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm guessing the solution is to add the extension library Widget Container, but have not done much with Widgets, can some one point me to an example? In my search I can find all kinds of digit clock widgets but not sure how to add it.
Thanks

Comment: Last time I checked, all digital devices showed a clock. Might not make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget container of the Extlib is nothing more than a set of HTML elements with CSS to look like a widget. Ok, it is a bit more and gives you some actions etc. but in your case the content counts. Did you search for client side Javascript solutions/addons displaying a digital clock, e.g. this one?
http://ticktoo.com/blog/35-simpleClock+-+jQuery+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Bill,

The amazing thing about xPages is that we don't need to follow normal Domino design practices and the entirety of modern web design is now open to us.

The trick to this is to use the package explorer and add the content into the webcontent folder in Designer. You can then access things like the js clock mentioned elsewhere on this page. I use Mark Roden's extjs tutorial as a way to get started in this world. That would let the service run locally.

You could also just have an iFrame pointing to a site on the internet.

But here is a pure javascript digital clock you can add to your page. I took the w3schools example and got it working with xpages. You should be able to add some nice styling to it to match your app. The checkTime function could just be "i<10" but I was getting errors in xPages when trying to do so.

```
<script>
function startTime() {
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
m = checkTime(m);
s = checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h+":"+m+":"+s;
var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
if (i==0|i==1|i==2|i==3|i==4|i==5|i==6|i==7|i==8|i==9) {i = "0" + i};  
return i;
}
</script>

<div id="txt"></div>




<xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[startTime()]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

Comment: This clock will work for standard 24hr local client time. You could probably just change some code to get it to display 12hr time by subtracting 12 if its over 12.